# No provider for AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j0LVc-zLh0) to set up a chat room application in Angular and I'm having problems with setting up AngularFire2.

I noticed that in [package.json file](https://github.com/wesdoyle/base-chat/blob/master/package.json) hes using `4.0.0-rc.1` so I changed mine version from `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"` to `"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1"`

Now my chat.service.ts imports look like this

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

    import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat.message.model';
```

However I was getting the following error on the FirebaseListObservable import

[image: chat.service.ts]

When I googled this error I came across [this post on github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1183) which suggests using `angularfire2/database-deprecated`. I did this and my project now compiles without any error. However, when I now navigate to `localhost:4200/chat` it redirects my app to `http://localhost:4200/` and I get the following error in my console

[image: console error]

When I google this error the top result is [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772474/no-provider-for-angularfiredatabase-angularfireauth) which tells me that AngularDatabase has been separated into its own module. But I'm confused about how to fix my issue. Am I copying his entire example into my `app.module.ts` file? Where am I getting this AngularFireModule api key from?

I want to follow along as closely as possible with the tutorial and my `app.module.ts` matches exactly what the [github tutorial has](https://github.com/wesdoyle/base-chat/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) as well as the exact same [chat.service.ts file](https://github.com/wesdoyle/base-chat/blob/master/src/app/services/chat.service.ts) with the exception that mine has `'angularfire2/database-deprecated'` instead of `'angularfire2/database'` . Where do I go from here? Here is my full app.module.ts file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChatFormComponent } from './chat-form/chat-form.component';
import { ChatRoomComponent } from './chat-room/chat-room.component';
import { MessagesFeedComponent } from './messages-feed/messages-feed.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './message/message.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list/user-list.component';
import { UserItemComponent } from './user-item/user-item.component';
import { ChatService } from './services/chat.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { appRoutes } from '../routes';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChatFormComponent,
    ChatRoomComponent,
    MessagesFeedComponent,
    MessageComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, ChatService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my chat service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat.message.model';


@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  user: any;
  chatMessages:FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]>;
  chatMessage: ChatMessage;
  userName: Observable<string>
  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth =>{
      if(auth !== undefined && auth !== null){
        this.user = auth;
      }
    })
   }

  sendMessage(msg: string){
    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    const email = this.user.email;
    this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
    this.chatMessages.push({
      message: msg,
      timeSent: timestamp,
      userName: this.userName,
      email: email
    });
    console.log('called sendMessage()!');
  }

  getTimeStamp(){
    const now = new Date();
    const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' + (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getUTCDate();
    const time = now.getUTCHours() + ':' + now.getUTCMinutes()  + ':' + now.getUTCSeconds();

    return (date + ' ' + time);
  }

  getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]>{
    return this.db.list('messages', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 25,
        orderByKey: true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: modify the import statement  as `AngularFireDatabaseModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score 3):

Import specifically.Import same module with the same packages.
As per your code:

`import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';`

In service you do :

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

AngularFireDatabaseModule imported from two other packages 'database' and 'database-deprecated' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**BE CONSISTENT IN WHAT YOU IMPORT AND WHAT YOU USE**

Make sure you are importing the same Angularfire2 and Firebase package at all places. From provided snapshots it appears that in NgModule you do

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

But in the service you do

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

**USE THE LATEST WORKING DEPENDENCIES**

Also the package.json on your GitHub repo looks as using old packages, please update.

**CONSIDER OTHER OPTIONS**
Also, you might consider using Firestore instead od the old real-time database, but be aware, these are two different things and they require different implementation.

**IDEA**

Try to update your project with following dependencies in your package.json

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
```

Truly, the "firebase": "4.8.0" is important. The rest I added are polyfills and updates to general packages (you do not have to use them if you are not comfortable with latest unstable versions). You can just overwrite your package.json and run npm install then.

Then simply import Firebase to your main AppModule like this:

```html
// General
import { BrowserModule           } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule                } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent            } from './app.component';

// Firebase
import { AngularFireModule       } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule   } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule  } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { environment             } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations : [
               AppComponent,
               ...
             ],
  imports      : [
               BrowserModule,
               ...,
               AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
               AngularFireAuthModule,
               AngularFirestoreModule,
               ...
             ],
  providers    : [ ... ],
  bootstrap    : [ AppComponent  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add all relevant modules from Firebase if needed (I just put Auth and Firestore to the example).

You should be able to use it in your services like this then:

```js
import { Injectable                    } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore,
         AngularFirestoreCollection,
         AngularFirestoreDocument      } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  constructor( private _fireStore: AngularFirestore ) { }
               
               ... some code ...
}
```

Comment: I did this and got the same issue

Comment: And it is only the FirebaseListObservable that is giving you the troubles or do you see some other issues as well?

Comment: The only issue I see is the error in my console that I took a screen shot above.

Comment: Make sure you are importing everywhere just from  "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next" and "firebase": "4.8.0"

Comment: When I do that I get messages saying 'cannot find name FirebaseListObservable' and 'cannot find name AngularFireDatabase' and 'cannot find name AngularFireAuth' in my chat service. Here is what the full file looks like.

https://pastebin.com/Tk4BfHYd

Comment: oh, sure, because you are mixing Firestore and Realtime DB altogether, but they are two distinctly different things ... in order to use Firestore, you need to change you environments references in your app, also change your logic (Firestore has specific methods) and even more, you have to switch your Firebase project from Realtime DB to Firestore ... Please, learn about Firestore at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: Have you tried just using import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database'; everywhere first before trying to pop in the Firestore?